# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in loop

Tags: javascript

I keep getting the same error in my code on line 21.

```
if(typeof jQuery === undefined){
    throw "jQuery is required for sapphire to work. Didn't you read the     README?";
}
(function ( $ ) {

$.fn.slider = (function(options,images) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      slideCount: 4,
      animationType:"none",
      slideDuration:2000,
      sliderSize:1100,
      looptimes:300000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    },options);
    for(var i = 0; i<options.looptimes; i++){
      var j = 0;
      $("#sapphire-slide").append("<img src='"+images[j]+"'>");
      setTimeout(function() {
        if(j<options.slideCount-1)
          j++;
         }else if(j===options.slideCount-1){
           j=0;
         }
      },options.slideDuration);
    }
);

})( jQuery );
```

I am not sure what is causing this error, and it looks like perfectly fine syntax to me. Thanks!

Comment: And which is line 21?

Comment: I don't that long integer for `looptimes` will go down well.

Comment: As I'm sure others here are telling themselves, this is a very poor question. We're not here to help with code formatting/missing braces. Please, use some kind of IDE for this.

Comment: there are code linting tools both in IDE's, in browsers  and online you can use that will tell you exactly what the problem is. Sytntax errors shouldn't be questions here

Comment: FYI, this is wrong: `typeof jQuery === undefined`. It will never be `true`. It's a very common mistake and one of the reasons to not use `typeof` when  merely testing for `undefined`. Just use `window.jQuery === undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

you've got an extra closing brace for the `if` in the function that you're passing to `setTimeout`:

```
if (j < options.slideCount - 1)
      j++;
// the errant closing brace is on the next line:
}
else if(j === options.slideCount - 1)
{
   j = 0;
}
```

Or, as others have mentioned, add an opening brace to the `if` to make a proper block:

```
if (j < options.slideCount - 1)
{   // you need this opening brace
      j++;
}
else if(j === options.slideCount - 1)
{
   j = 0;
}
```

Comment: Or rather missing the opening brace.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the opening `{` on the `if` and you are missing the closing `}` on the second last line, before the `)`:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.slider = (function (options, images) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            slideCount: 4,
            animationType: "none",
            slideDuration: 2000,
            sliderSize: 1100,
            looptimes: 300000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        }, options);
        for (var i = 0; i < options.looptimes; i++) {
            var j = 0;
            $("#sapphire-slide").append("<img src='" + images[j] + "'>");
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (j < options.slideCount - 1) {  // <--- add this {
                    j++;
                } else if (j === options.slideCount - 1) {
                    j = 0;
                }
            }, options.slideDuration);
        } 
    });    // <--- add a } on this line

})(jQuery);
```

Note that fixing this sort of thing is just a matter of counting brackets and parentheses and making sure they're balanced.